# How to specify a default value for argument list processed by click?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, python-click

I have this line of code that is expected to grab all the file names passed to my Python script:

```
@click.argument("logs", nargs=-1, type=click.File('r'), required=1)
```

When no file names are passed, I want to default to `-`, that is, the standard input.  So, if I try:

```
@click.argument("logs", nargs=-1, type=click.File('r'), required=1, default="-")
```

click becomes unhappy and throws this error:

> TypeError: nargs=-1 in combination with a default value is not supported.

Is there a workaround for this? I tried setting `nargs=0` but that throws a different error:

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: For what it's worth, relevant [issue on github](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/390) (i.e. they didn't fix it, they disallowed it explicitly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `click` had explicitly stated that they disabled this particular feature needed by the question, as reported on [this issue](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/390) on their project, a workaround will be needed and that can be easily implemented as part of the Python function (instead of some more pile on bash code as suggested by the comment on the other answer).

The workaround is simply drop the required argument and handle the missing logs using a statement (similar to what [this commit](https://github.com/samuller/pgmerge/commit/34b6e505c3550e4880d900c5093e5ab6d06f0c79) did which referenced the linked issue):

```
import sys
import click

@click.command()
@click.argument("logs", nargs=-1, type=click.File('r'))
def main(logs):
    if not logs:
        logs = (sys.stdin,)
    print(logs)
    # do stuff with logs

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Example execution

```
$ python fail.py 
(<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>,)
$ python fail.py -
(<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>,)
$ python fail.py foo bar
(<_io.TextIOWrapper name='foo' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>, <_io.TextIOWrapper name='bar' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>)
```

Answer (score 5):

To default to `stdin` for a potentially empty list of files, you can define a custom argument class like:

#### Custom Class:

```
class FilesDefaultToStdin(click.Argument):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['nargs'] = -1
        kwargs['type'] = click.File('r')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def full_process_value(self, ctx, value):
        return super().process_value(ctx, value or ('-', ))
```

Defining this behavior as a class provides for easy reuse.

#### To use the Custom Class:

```
@click.command()
@click.argument("logs", cls=FilesDefaultToStdin)
def main(logs):
    ...
```

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.argument()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Argument` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the `cls` parameter. So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Argument` in our own class and over-ride the desired methods.

In this case, we override `click.Argument.full_process_value()`.  In our `full_process_value()` we look for an empty argument list, and if empty, we add the `-` (stdin) argument to the list.

In addition, we auto assign the `nargs=-1` and the `type=click.File('r')` arguments.

Comment: `full_process_value()` was removed in click 8 but `process_value()` works

Answer (score -1):

The following code:

```
import click


@click.command()
@click.option('--logs', '-l', multiple=True, default='-')
def cli(logs):
    click.echo('\n'.join(logs))
```

Will produce the following:

```
$ myhello -l foo.log -l bar.log -l baz.log
foo.log
bar.log
baz.log
$ myhello
-
```

So if you just could call your program differently with repeated parameters instead that would the workaround you are looking for.

Comment: This changes the semantics of what the OP wanted, so yes this would just be a workaround that does not address the actual problem.

Comment: in that case i would just add a simple wrapper around the above in bash.